# Embed camera in Activity/Fragment like Instagram

Tags: android, android-camera

I have an app that sometimes needs to send a photo of a receipt during a confirmation process, and I'd like to have the camera on the same screen, even if the camera preview and the photo taken doesn't have an aspect ratio of 1:1 (like Instagram).

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use external camera app with the help of intents: https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html
2. You can embed camera in your app. It's covered in the docs too: https://developer.android.com/training/camera/cameradirect.html

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I forget to say that I'd like to embed the camera, but you already give me the direction.. thanks.

Comment: I have found the **CWAC Camera** lib from commonsguy that helps to set and configure  camera and take photos simply, but my issue is to embed this on the activity/fragment.